# Javascript: Using a script for ajax-loaded data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I have a webpage on which I want to output events. These events are outputted via ajax via a php script. When the user on the bottom of each event clicks on the link "view event" I want a modal window pop up. I have been using the magnificPopup script.

This popup script works totally fine on pages where the data is already there and not loaded in via ajax. The script takes the id of the clicked button and opens the HTML content as modal whose ID is identical with the href-tag of the clicked button.

**EDITED**

I have several events being loaded in via ajax:

- Every element has the same class.
- Every event gets loaded in with the respective modal window.
- The href of the button, which is equivalent to the id of the modal window to be opened, and the id of the button, which is used inside the magnificPopup script command, are both generated dynamically and are NOT KNOWN beforehand when the page loads.

Here come **one example of one event div and its modal window div** (remember: they are not contained in the webpage beforehand, they are loaded in via ajax):

```
// Event div
<div class="event">
<a href="modal_admin_view-69" id="show_modal_admin_view-69" class="event_action_button">view</a>
</div>
</a>

// Modal window
<div id="modal_admin_view-69" class="mfp-hide"><p>I am the modal window!</p></div>
```

What does my magnific popup script on my webpage need to look like in order to flexibly enabling any event button to open the modal window it is supposed to open, based on its href?

I have tried it with the following on my webpage, but it does not work:

```
$('body').on('click', '.event_action_button', function() {

    $.magnificPopup.open({
        removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
        callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function() {
            this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');           },
        midClick: true
    });

});
```

Comment: "I have already tried to output the script together with the event via the PHP script, but I cannot get this to work." - Why didn't this work? What was the error? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initiate a direct binding for magnific popup to the element, but the element doesn't exist in the DOM tree until it's populated by AJAX.  To fix this, you need to use a delegated binding, such as .on():

[jQuery .on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Try something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#id_of_event_button', function() {
  $.magnificPopup.open({
      removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
      callbacks: {
          // callbacks
      },
      midClick: true
  });
});
```